# CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED error in tensorflow model on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, rocky-os

I am trying to compile a tensorflow model using UNET architecture **(OS->Rocky Linux 8.6, GPU->Quadro P620, Tensoflow-> 2.11.0, CUDA->11.6)**. The model works fine on CPU and google colab. But when i try to run it on GPU then the following problem comes during model.fit.

> CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
> in tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(5750): 'cudnnBatchNormalizationForwardTrainingEx( cudnn.handle(), mode,
> bn_ops, &one, &zero, x_descriptor.handle(), x.opaque(),
> x_descriptor.handle(), side_input.opaque(), x_descriptor.handle(),
> y->opaque(), scale_offset_descriptor.handle(), scale.opaque(),
> offset.opaque(), exponential_average_factor, batch_mean_opaque,
> batch_var_opaque, epsilon, saved_mean->opaque(),
> saved_inv_var->opaque(), activation_desc.handle(), workspace.opaque(),
> workspace.size(), reserve_space.opaque(), reserve_space.size())'

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have installed `CUDA 11.6` for Tensorflow 2.11. You need to install **CUDA 11.2** and **cuDNN 8.1** as mentioned in the below tested build configurations for linux: [image]

Please follow all the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) along with the specified **Hardware and Software requirements** to enable tensorflow with **GPU Support** in your system.